# Eigen solver compute with a MatrixXd throwing out an error

Tags: c++, eigen

Hi everyone for some reason I have to use Eigen matrices and eigen solvers.
In the following code :

```
        MatrixXd matrix(1, 3);
        int cpt = 1;
        for (QVector<float> v : coordinates_matrix) {

            matrix.row(cpt-1) = Vector3d(v[0],v[1],v[2]);
            cpt += 1;

            matrix.conservativeResize(cpt,Eigen::NoChange);

        }

        Eigen::EigenSolver<MatrixXd> solver;
        solver.compute(matrix);
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to compute the matrix (last line of the bloc of code) The app is crashing throwing this error :

```
Eigen::EigenSolver<MatrixType>& Eigen::EigenSolver<_MatrixType>::compute(const Eigen::EigenBase<OtherDerived>&, bool) [with InputType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>; _MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>]:  assertion « matrix.cols() == matrix.rows() » failed.
```

If anyone has any idea or lead I'd be glad to hear it please, thank you.

Comment: It only makes sense to find eigenvalues for a square matrix. There are a different number of rows and columns in your matrix. I am not sure what you ultimately want to do, but maybe you would prefer to use SVD which will work with  matrices of any dimension.

Comment: @wcochran ohhh well ok thanks, to be honest I'm a bit lost concerning PCA

Comment: PCA requires a square positive semidefinite matrix for eigen analysis. Perhaps you wish to find the eigenvalues  of `matrix.transpose() * matrix` which will have these properties -- that is typically what PCA uses. You can also perform PCA using SVD.

Comment: I am assuming PCA = principal component analysis.

Comment: @wcochran yes this is what i'm trying to achieve (the whole project is mesh labelling using CNNs) and for this we need to extract features of each faces) thats why we are assuming eigen values are the part we should extract. Thanks a lot i'll try this tomorrow !